# Is the particle-hole transform rigorous in infinite-dims?

Tags: hilbert-space, mathematical-physics

$\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}$Let me only consider fermions, i.e., fermionic Fock space $\mathscr{F}$ of a single-particle Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$. Let us assume that $\dim \mathscr{H}=\aleph_0$ (infinitely countable).

Based on my understanding, the particle-hole transform (in the most general sense) is either a unitary or anti-unitary operator $W$ on the Fock space which takes
$$
W c^*(x)W^*=c(x)
$$
where $x$ is some orthonormal basis of $\mathscr{H}$, or more generally,
$$
W c^*(\varphi) W^*=c(\varphi)\quad \text{or} \quad c(\bar{\varphi})
$$
where $\varphi\in \mathscr{H}$, the *bar* notation is the anti-linear complex conjugation $C$ with respect to the basis $x$ and the "or" is depending on whether $W$ is unitary or anti-unitary.

Now I know that if $\dim {\mathscr{H}} <\infty$ is finite-dim, I can construct such a unitary/anti-unitary operator basically by the Bogoliubov transform (**Theorem 2.2** in *Bach, V., Lieb, E. H., & Solovej, J. P. (1994). Generalized Hartree-Fock theory and the Hubbard model. Journal of statistical physics, 76(1), 3-89.*). **Indeed**, the theorem tells us that if $u,v$ are (special, but not important to this question) bounded linear operators on $\mathscr{H}$ and $\tr {v^*v} <\infty$, then there exists a unitary operator $W$ on the Fock space such that
$$
Wc^*(\varphi) W^*=c^*(u\varphi)+c(v\bar{\varphi})
$$
Taking $v=I$ and $u=0$ and we obtain a unitary particle-hole transform $W$. Moreover, if $K$ is the second-quantization of complex conjugation $C$ on the Fock space, i.e., $K=\bigoplus C\otimes \cdots \otimes C$, then $KW$ is the anti-unitary particle-transform operator. **Either way, the essential thing** is that $\mathscr{H}$ is finite-dim so that $\tr {v^*v} <\infty$. In Solovej's *Many Body Quantum Mechanics*, it's also proven that $\tr {v^*v} <\infty$ (Shale-Stinespring condition) is a necessary condition for such a Bogoliubov unitary transform to exist (though I haven't checked the proof).

**Knowing all this**, I can't understand why such a particle-hole transform would exist in an infinite-dim space, despite seeing it often mentioned in such context. Maybe I'm overlooking something, or maybe it's just that we only care about finite-dim system which are taken to the "thermodynamic limit" so that our systems are always finite-dim (albeit very large).

*Side note*. Notice that my particle-hole transform transforms all particles to holes and vice-versa, even though the usual way is to transform particles with energy $<0$ to holes and keep the particles with energy $\ge 0$ as particles (as in the Fermi sea). In this case, as long as the number of states wth energy $<0$ is finite, then the aforementioned particle-hole transform is well-defined, even if the entire single-particle space is infinite-dim. What I'm basically asking is what happens if the number of states with energy $<0$ is infinite too.

**EDIT**. I realized that we probably never actually need to consider a case where the number of states with energy $<0$ is infinite. Because if we do, this implies that the Fermi sea ground state has an an energy of $ = -\infty$. What those texts probably mean is that if were to take the thermodynamic limit, then the number of states with energy $<0$  would $\to \infty$.

Comment: Careful about what you mean by dimension. For this look up the definition of Hamel vs Schauder basis. Even for your garden variety Hilbert space in QM, the (algebraic) dimension, ie, the cardinality of a Hamel basis is not Aleph 0. It's uncountable. What is countable is the cardinality of a Hilbert basis which is not a basis because you are allowed infinite linear combinations. The right concept here is that of separable Hilbert or more generally topological vector space.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam I'm not sure if I fully understand your comment. If you mean that I should have been more specific (i.e., change infinite-dim to countable infinite-dim), then I agree (but to my defense, I did assume this in the first sentence), but to be honest, I never encountered in QM an uncountable/non-separable Hilbert space.

Comment: I am saying there are two different notions of dimension. The size of a Hamel basis vs that of a Schauder basis (lookup Wikipedia for definitions). I agree that it's rather hard to find nonseparable Hilbert spaces in QM. Take $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ which is the Hilbert space for say the harmonic oscillator. There, a Hamel basis would be uncountably infinite. On the other hand, a Hilbert basis (e.g., the eigenstates of the harmonic oscillator) which is an example of Schauder, basis would have countably many elements.